# Enormous form: how can I do it in Android?

Tags: android, layout

I'm developing an Android Tablet application with Android 3.1 SDK.

I have to implement a form in an Android Tablet. Now I'm doing on one screen with TableLayout, TableRow, TextView, Spinner, buttons, etc.

At this moment I have more than 80 views and then I get a warning about it.

The form is divided into sections and I think I can divide it into tabs but I don't know if I will have the same problem (I'm very new on Android development and now I learning how tabs work).

What do you recommend me? I will have, probably, 160 view or more.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you split this huge form into multiple screens / steps somehow, it seems much more useable and managable to me. You could use fragments to hold the steps, and use some paging mechanism to navigate between these fragments. By switching fragments and saving their state you can keep the number of Views on the screen relatively low.
Check out the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) component for this to navigate between fragments by swiping. Or you may use the plain old button based navigation (next/previous step e.g.).

If you really need to display all the form elements on one screen and want to keep the number of instantiated Views, you may be able to do this by using the virtualizing ListView, though it seems quite awkward to me. ListView constructs the rows as needed during scrolling, and you need to tell its adapter that you have X type of rows where X is the number of form-parts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use a ViewPager, can I use separate Activities?

Comment: Of course you can use separate activities. But you can't put Activities into a ViewPager, only Fragments or Views. You you could e.g. create separate Activities for different forms, and dissect the forms into fragments, showing them using ViewPagers.

Comment: So, I will need to move all the logic related to this form's "fragment" to Fragment class, isn't it?

Comment: Another question: if I'm using Android 3.1 SDK, is there a replacement for ViewPager? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you logically break this `Enormous form` and using something like a `Next` button show the form in multiple activities. This would keep the screen clean, won't bombard the user with too much of information and finally won't give the warning of excess views on screen.